# Ubuntu12.04 is not booting after connecting DVD Player. Please help

Tags: boot, grub2

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. Yesterday I connected a DVD player to my system, Now I've got a problem with booting. I get message like:

```
Busy box 2.xx
............      ...
dev/disk/uidb<some numbers> does not exist
initrams
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you boot your computer, enter the BIOS
2. Make sure that the 1st boot device isn't set to the DVD player.
3. Ensure the 1st boot device is set to the hard drive that your OS is installed on. (If you have only one hard drive then your job is made that much easier)

Comment: Yes, I have set 1st booting device as HDD and I have only 1 HDD.

Comment: What happens if you disconnect the DVD player? Does it boot normally again or still the same problem?

Comment: Yes, It boots normally. I have some Physics videos in DVD.

Comment: What if you just plug your DVD player in after your computer is turned on? (I realize this is a shortcut and doesn't actually solve the problem)

Comment: My system supports IDE drive only. I've to close the case again. However will try once. Thanx

Comment: Oh. Sorry I was assuming it was a USB drive. Check the master/slave  jumpers are properly set on the DVD and HDD